# Upload image/pdf file to Suite CRM upload directory via its endpoint URL

Tags: node.js, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have my Suite CRM v10.22 installed on google Compute Engine over ubuntu over Apache webserver (Dev env) and its endpoint lets say "abc .com" and I have a node application which I am planning to host to google cloud run. The thing is, I want the node application to save the pdf/files directly to the upload directory of suite crm. I have removed the htaccess rule for the upload directory and it is currently open. ex - xyz.com/uploads.

I have tried uploading the pdf via post request to the upload directory via its URL. It is showing success but the file is not showing into the upload directory under suitecrm. Please check the screenshot attached below.

Please let me know is it possible to directly upload to the suite crm upload directory via post method by its endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading is usually done uploading a Document or a Note.

You can do it using the Rest API, the new v8 API or a regular POST with the PHP_SESSID cookie set and valid.

This is an example POST to SUITEURL/index.php for creating a Document.

```
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="module"
Documents
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="record"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="isDuplicate"
false
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"
Save
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="return_module"
Cases
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="return_action"
SubPanelViewer
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="return_id"
88ef0da5-e7e8-9389-3593-5dcf954c70b6
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="module_tab"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_role"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relate_to"
documents_cases
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relate_id"
88ef0da5-e7e8-9389-3593-5dcf954c70b6
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="offset"
1
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="old_id"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent_id"
88ef0da5-e7e8-9389-3593-5dcf954c70b6
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent_type"
Cases
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="full_form"
full_form
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status_id"
Active
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deleteAttachment"
0
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc_id"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc_url"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename_old_doctype"
Sugar
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename_escaped"
-----------------------------20663247957525777792049859544
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename_file"; filename="Logo Lionix-320x320.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/api-4_1/